# Partial update of Hibernate Model

Tags: java, hibernate

What is the best practice for updating a model where only certain fields are meant to be updated?

Eg.

If I have a person model with:

Name
Birthdate
Address

And a form where I want to update only:

Address

The two options I can currently see are:

1. To have a custom form model that has only address - on postback call the DB to retrieve my object to fill in Name and Birthdate, then persist back to the DB.
2. Custom update SQL to only update the relevant fields.

I'd prefer to make use of the hibernate model if possible, so I'm using #1 currently.

Is there a better way?

Comment: is this a performance related issue or a business case issue, as in name and address have changed but you only want the address updated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How Hibernate constructs an SQL Update can be configured to update only the fields that changed, using [an attribute called `dynamic-update` on the class mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html).

If hibernate leaves useful-looking functionality like this deactivated by default it's because there are trade-offs to be made. The linked documentation goes on to say:

> The dynamic-update and dynamic-insert settings are not inherited by subclasses, so they can also be specified on the  or  elements. Although these settings can increase performance in some cases, they can actually decrease performance in others.

Comment: +1, just to note that if using annotations you can have `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate=true)`

Comment: Unfortunately due to time constraints, I've had to move on for now. This seems like the best option and I will test it out when I get a chance. Thanks!

Comment: @Donald: be aware that if hibernate leaves useful-looking functionality like this deactivated by default it's because there are trade-offs to be made. the document i linked to says, "The dynamic-update and dynamic-insert settings are not inherited by subclasses, so they can also be specified on the <subclass> or <joined-subclass> elements. Although these settings can increase performance in some cases, they can actually decrease performance in others."

Answer (score 0):

Best Practice is to skip performance optimization until you need it.

Comment: Partial updates are more usually a correctness issue, rather than a performance issue - the idea is to avoid clobbering a concurrent update because your view of the data is out of date.

Comment: @Barry Kelly: Be careful when using partial updates to fix correctness issue: if the partial updated values are not independent of each other (this depends on the use case), then partial updates (without `@Version` attribute) can make the correctness issue even more worse.